# linking gmail address to Microsoft Outlook on home computer

Tags: microsoft-outlook, gmail

I just obtained my gmail address. How do I have it recognized by Microsoft Outlook on my home computer in order to receive and send emails?

Answer (score 1):

First thing first: Enable POP / IMAP on your Gmail (go to gmail.com, login, and go into the Settings page, under Forwarding POP/IMAP tab)

And then go here and Google Support will guide you through the full step by step instruction:
https://support.google.com/mail/troubleshooter/1668960?rd=1

Some setting recap from the page:

```
Incoming settings
(IMAP Method)
IMAP server: imap.gmail.com
Port: 993
Security type: SSL (always)

(POP Method)
Incoming Mail (POP3) Server: pop.gmail.com
Use SSL: Yes
Port: 995

Outgoing settings
SMTP server: smtp.gmail.com
Port: 465
Security type: SSL (always)
```

Hope this helps.